# On existence of a surjection from (0, 1) onto a compact metric space X

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Given any compact metric space X, does there exist a surjection from the open unit interval (0, 1) onto X?

This problem stumps me. I have tried a few approaches but to no avail. Is there some fact that/theorem I need to use while solving this? Or, do I construct such a function explicitly?

Comment: Separability of $X$ implies that its cardinality is at most that of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Indeed... I can see another solution through your argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every compact metric space $X$ is the image of a continuous function from the Cantor set $\mathfrak c$ onto $X$. Since $\mathfrak c$ and $(0,1)$ have the same cardinal, there is a continuous surjective function from $(0,1)$ onto $X$.

Comment: There is no continuous function from $(0,1)$ onto $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: The question makes no reference to continuity.

Comment: I see; you are right.

Comment: Thanks so much... I appreciate it.